# Explicit resource loading in Ogre (Mogre)

Tags: ogre, assets, resource-management

I am just starting to learn Mogre and what I would like to do is to be able to load resources 'explicitly' (i.e. I just provide an absolute path instead of using a resource group tied to a directory).

This is very different to *manually* loading resources, which I believe in Ogre has a very specific meaning, to build up the object using Ogres methods. I want to use Ogres resource management system/resource loading code, but to have finer control over which files are loaded and in what groups they are.

I remember reading how to do this but cannot find the page again; I think its possible to do something like:

- Declare a resource group
- Declare the resource(s) (this is when the actual resource file name is provided)
- Initialise the resource group to actually load the resource(s)

Is this the correct procedure? If so, is there any example code showing how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried asking at the Ogre and mogre forums?  I've found the old timers to be very helpful over there.

Comment: @Patrick, I will do if no-one here answers, it does look like a good forum (part of the reason I decided to learn it) but I'm also aware that that may be in part because most people who try Ogre do their best to find the answers on their own first and I don't want to take advantage with my newbie Qs :D; GameDev seemed like a good place for a Q. like this plus on Google its not exactly an unpopular request (in one form or another) so I thought it would be useful to have it here. (If I do get an answer there I'll update here in any case!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this article: http://misterblue.com/programming/dynamic-ogre-resources